# Can i add short video(addvertisement video) before the actual streaming video starts in MPmovieplayerviewcontroller

Tags: iphone

During streaming video in iphone it takes some time (=10 seconds) to start actual video play back.Now i wantuser to watch sme kind of advertisement video in that time.Is that possible in MPMoviePlayerviewcontroller.
Thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes simply start the ad-video first while loading in the background the actual video in NSData, then as soon as the ad-video is ended load the mpmovieplayer with the data

Comment: Thanx Bob,will try and get back to u